# Pixel Art in Gimp

Tags: gimp, pixel, pixel-art

I want to create some Pixel Art images with the help of gimp. when I wanted a pixel field of 8x8 I used to simply create an image with the width and height of 8 and used the pencil with the pixel brush and the size of 1. Then I scaled the Image to 800x800 and all the colours got blurry!! :( Then I created a new Image with the size of 800x800 used the pencil with the pixel brush and used the size 100. Unfortunately and for what ever reason the pencil wasn't exactly 100pixels big... Do you guys know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part is realy easy.

- Don't scale your image using any interpolation method. Choose **None** in the dialog box.
- Use exact multipliers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create layers with 100x100 pixel squares on a 800x800 pixels document, move them around and changing its colors.

Comment: Then I had to create 64 layers one by one?